# Is there a better way to return values with hash arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, arguments

I am new to Ruby, and I am just learning hash argument.
  I just have question about how to return values if I use hash arguments

I create a class called Test, including a method called test_method with hash arguments like the following code:

```
 class Test
     def test_method(names={})
       names[:firstname]
       names[:lastname]
       return names
     end
  end
```

And I call it like

```
    test = Test.new
    myname = test.test_method(firstname: 'Tester', lastname: 'Testing')

    puts myname
```

Certainly, the results I got are " firstname Tester lastname Testing "

So, I use other way. 
I set two instance variables @firstname and @lastname for names[:firstname] names[:lastname], like the following:

```
def test_method(names={})
        @firstname = names[:firstname]
        @lastname = names[:lastname]
        return @firstname, @lastname
end
```

I am able to get results I want, but if I have more than 10 arguments need to be set?
If there a better way to get result?

Comment: Contrary to what you wrote, `test_method` is not a class method.

Comment: ah, yes. Thanks. It is just a method

Comment: @user2727616 `puts myname` prints `{:firstname=>"Tester", :lastname=>"Testing"}` on my system, not just `firstname Tester lastname Testing`. What's your desired output? What should `test_method` return? An array, a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If all of your hash keys correspond to the instance variable names, you can simply loop through your key-value pairs and use `instance_variable_set`:

```
def test_method(names = {})
  names.each do |key, value|
    instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use "instance_variable_set". It is more flexible.

Comment: This method could become the source of a debugging nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
def test_method(names = {})
  names.values # no need to write even return, in ruby last statement of method, is   automatically returnd
 end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also read Ruby doc: hash part, but I didn't know I don't need to specify symbols in test_method. It will return keys or values if I just use names.keys or names.values